# How do I get a Factory of specific classes implementing a generic interface without having to cast?

Tags: java, generics, factory

So I got an interface `SuperType` and a bunch of implementing classes `TypeA`, `TypeB`and so on. I also got a top-level interface which has a parameterized method:

```
public interface UsedByProductThing<T extends SuperType> {
    public T doStuff(T one);
}
```

I got a factory (see below) producing objects implementing `GeneralProduct`:

```
public interface GeneralProduct<T extends SuperType> {
    T doSomething(T input);
}
```

Here is the implementing `ProductA`:

```
public class ProductA implements GeneralProduct<TypeA> {
    UsedByProductThing<TypeA> in;

    public ProductA(UsedByProductThing<TypeA> in) {
        this.in = in;
        in.doStuff(new TypeA());
    }

    @Override
    public TypeA doSomething(TypeA input) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And now the factory in question:

```
public class GeneralFactory {
    public static <T extends SuperType> GeneralProduct<T> createProduct(
            int type, UsedByProductThing<T> in) {
        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            return (GeneralProduct<T>) new ProductA((UsedByProductThing<TypeA>) in);
            // at this point, i want to return a "new ProductA(in)" preferably
            // without casting
            // or at least without the cast of the argument.
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("type unkown.");
        }
    }
}
```

As commented, I want that factory-method to not use a cast. I understand that the return type has to be GeneralProduct, but I can't think of a way omitting the cast (and it gives me an "unchecked cast"-warning, too). Also, I can't think of a way omitting the cast of the argument. I'm able to restructure the whole code if it's necessary to get rid of the "unsafe" casting at that place. Can you tell me a way that would be nice and smooth here?

Also, please edit my question as you like - I don't know how to adress the issue correctly in the title.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure why you want / need to get rid of the cast of the return type, it is fine. Regarding the unsafe cast of the parameter, this is because you are making an assumption that if the user passed `1` for `type`, they will always pass a `UsedByProductThing<TypeA>`. If you KNOW that the using code will ALWAYS satisfy this contract, you are OK. Otherwise you have issues.

Comment: One thing to remember, is that due to type-erasure all the generic types are converted to `Object` at runtime anyway. So `UsedByProductThing` becomes `UsedByProduceThing<Object>` and `GeneralProduce` becomes `GeneralProduce<Object>`. Keep this in mind before trying to work yourself in circles dealing with generic casting.

Comment: I know about type erasure - I just never got to the point where such kind of (generics) type casting was really necessary (since I never used Java before there were generics). 
Also, why is there even a cast like `((UsedByProductThing<TypeA>) in)` while `in` is of type `(UsedByProductThing<T>)`? If I understand that correctly, it's just there for the compiler before the type-erasure and is completely omitted afterwards - right?

Comment: Yes, the casting is required to ensure you know what you are doing. At runtime, everything is Object so no casting is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't avoid casting because

- you have `in` which has type `UsedByProductThing<T>` which you want to turn into a `UsedByProductThing<TypeA>` and the compiler has no way of knowing that `T` is `TypeA`
- ProductA is `GeneralProduct<TypeA>` and again the compiler doesn't know that `T` is a `TypeA` here either.

The only way to avoid cast is to replace `T` with `TypeA`

```
    public static GeneralProduct<TypeA> createProduct(
            int type, UsedByProductThing<TypeA> in) {
        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                return new ProductA(in);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("type unkown.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which would render my createProduct-method useless. Thank you very much for making that clear!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's any clean way to do this.  Also, i think any casting the way you're doing it is inherently unsafe anyway, since someone could pass a "type" value that's not compatible with the "in" value.

That being said, these kinds of inherent unchecked casts are common when dealing with generics.  You should avoid them if possible, but sometimes, you can't, and should just add the annotation to suppress if you really just want to get rid of the compiler warning.

@Suppress("unchecked")

Alternately why not take a builder approach?

```
public inteface Builder<T extends SuperType> {
    public GeneralProduct<T> createProduct(UsedByProductThing<T> thing);
}

public class BuilderFactory {
    public static <T extends SuperType> Builder<T> createBuilder(Class<T> clazz) {
       if (clazz.equals(ProductA.class)) {
          return new (Builder<T>) ProductABuilder();
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

And then use it as such (assuming you have created a builder imple:

```
Builder<ProductA> builder = BuilderFactory.createBuilder(ProductA.class);
UsedByProductThing<ProductA> thing = ...;
ProductA product = builder.createProduct(thing);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try the Builder concept.

Answer (score 0):

dont return

```
"GeneralProduct<T>"
```

, better you return

```
"GeneralProduct<?>"
```

, so no need to cast the result.

But anyway, you have to cast the parameter for "ProductA"!